# How to set $variable as a DATE_FORMAT in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created one variable for changing date format in MySQL query but it is not working for me so is there any way to use a variable as a date-format in MySQl query ?

My code is here

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect();
    mysql_select_db();
    $dateFormat = '%d-%m-%Y';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(2014-11-18, $dtFormat) AS niceDate FROM TableName;");
    $data = array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result, true) )
    {
        $data[] = $row;    
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to add `'` single quotes around your date. `'2014-11-18'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `$dateFormat` instead of `$dtFormat` as a string in MySQL.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect();
mysql_select_db();
$dateFormat = '%d-%m-%Y';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT('2014-11-18', '".$dateFormat."') AS niceDate FROM TableName;");
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result, true) )
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Yaa, thanks FIA2008, it was my mistake while writing variable in query. i used `DATE_FORMAT('2014-11-18', $dateFormat) AS niceDate` instead of  `DATE_FORMAT('2014-11-18', '".$dateFormat."') AS niceDate`.

Working Fine. 
Thanks Again :) .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add both quotation marks to show PHP it's a String AND quotation marks to show SQL that it should still be a String.

Try this:

```
$dateFormat = "'%d-%m-%Y'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `$dateFormat = '%d-%m-%Y';` is working for me.